# Converting a cell to a 4D array

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array, reshape, cell-array

My data came in a certain form but I need it in another. I have tried `reshape` and `permute`, yet, I did not achieve the desired result.

#### Input:

A = {5 x 1} cell array, where every cell is `{300 x 18 single}`.

#### Expected Output:

A 4D array of size 18 x 300 x 1 x5:

```
A( 1,  1,1,1) = 0.5
A( 1,  2,1,1) = 0.7
....
A( 1,300,1,1) = 0.8
...
A(18,300,1,1) = 0.99
...
...
...
A(18,300,1,5) = 0.89
```

(values above are random)

This is my attempt,

```
z = cellfun(@(X) permute(X,[3 2 1]),A,'UniformOutput',false);
```

Which resulted in

```
z =
  5×1 cell array
    {1×18×300 single}
    {1×18×300 single}
    {1×18×300 single}
    {1×18×300 single}
    {1×18×300 single}
```

Comment: Based on the example at the end, it appears that you want `A` to be 18 x 300 x 1 x **5**, and not 18 x 300 x 1 x 1 like you said. Please confirm.

Comment: What are these terms `:1`, `:2`,  `:300`? This is not a valid syntax. If you want a 18x300x1x5, it'd be better to keep it as a 3D array of size 18x300x5. There is no purpose of 3rd dimension as 1

Answer (score 2):

I think `permute` and `reshape` *are* the way to go. Here's how I'd do it:

```matlab
function z = q56764340(A)
if ~nargin
  %% Generate some data:
  A = reshape(num2cell(zeros(300,18,5,'single'), [1,2]),[], 1);
  %{
  A =
    5×1 cell array
      {300×18 single}
      {300×18 single}
      {300×18 single}
      {300×18 single}
      {300×18 single}
  %}
end

%% Convert to a 4d numeric array:
z = permute( ...                  this does 300x18x1x5 -> 18x300x1x5
      cell2mat( ...               this does 1x1x1x5 -> 300x18x1x5
        reshape(A,1,1,1,[])), ... this does 5x1 -> 1x1x1x5
      [2,1,3,4]);
```

Comment: Nice answer, although I find `cell2mat(reshape(A,1,1,1,[]))` a rather more esoteric way to unpack the cells than `cat(4,A{:})`

Answer (score 1):

You just need to take [transpose](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/transpose.html) of every cell.

```
z = cellfun(@transpose, A, 'un', 0);
```

What you are looking for is a 2D array in every cell. There is no difference between 18x300 and 18x300x1x1. Every array has infinite singleton dimensions.

---

**Edit:**
It seems that you're looking for a 4D array of size 18x300x1x5. In that case, further use:

```
z = cat(4, z{:});
```

Third dimension as 1 doesn't seem to be serving any purpose here. It'd be better to have a 3D array of size 18x300x5 instead.

```
z = cat(3, z{:});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and the explanation. But what I am looking for a 4D data. Such as in each of the A{5x1} cell contains data of size 18 x300 x1 x1. Now after converting it to the 4-d numeric array, it will turn as: A(1,:1,:1,:1)=0.5,A(1,:2,:1,:1)=0.7....A(1,:300,:1,:1)=0.8...A(18,:300,:1,:1)=0.99....A(18,:300,:1,:5)=0.89. Can you suggest me now how to do this?